# Fit boxes dynamically in a container with flexbox

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox

I want to arrange boxes dynamically in a container using flexbox. The arrangement looks like this:

[image: Display rules]

For three or four boxes, the boxes should arrange like in first pic.
For six boxes, the boxes should fit in two rows with three columns. However for seven boxes, the arrangement should look like that displayed in second picture, and so on.

The width and height of the container are fixed.

Is this possible purely with Flexbox?

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">AB</div>
  <div class="box">CD</div>
  <div class="box">EF</div>
  <div class="box">GH</div>
  <div class="box">IJ</div>
  <div class="box">KL</div>
  <div class="box">MN</div>
  <div class="box">OP</div>
  <div class="box">QR</div>
  <div class="box">ST</div>
  <div class="box">UV</div>
  <div class="box">XY</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
}

.box {
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
function align(nodes) {
    var nodeLength = nodes.length;
    if(nodeLength == 1) {
  // nodes occupies entire box
  }

  else if (nodeLength == 2) {
    // nodes displayed in two columns
  }

  else if(nodeLength > 2 && nodeLength < 5) {
  // nodes displayed in two rows, two columns
  }

  else if(nodeLength > 4 && nodeLength <= 6) {
  // display in two columns and three rows
  }

 /*
   .
   .
   .
   and so on
 */
}

var boxes = document.getElementsByClassName('box');

align(boxes);
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/dk49/ye4Lv48u/1/) is a fiddle for the same.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, there is a way. I'm just not very familiar with it. Try looking at css grid as well. I think there is  `fill` property that might facilitate this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Flexbox solution (without JavaScript)

Calculate width and height of each item in the square as follows

```
.square-item {
  width: calc(100% / n);
  height: calc(100% / n);
}
```

`n` is number of columns (or rows).

#### Example

```css
.square-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.square {
  --size: 160px;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: flex-start;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
}

.square>div {
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px #abc;
  position: relative;
}

.square p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.square.s-2_2>div {
  width: calc(100% / 2);
  height: calc(100% / 2);
}

.square.s-3_3>div {
  width: calc(100% / 3);
  height: calc(100% / 3);
}

.square.s-4_4>div {
  width: calc(100% / 4);
  height: calc(100% / 4);
}


/* Add more custom square classes */


/* ... */
```

```html
<div class="square-wrapper">
  <div class="square s-2_2">
    <div>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square-wrapper">
  <div class="square s-3_3">
    <div>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>8</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>9</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square-wrapper">
  <div class="square s-4_4">
    <div>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>8</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>9</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>10</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>11</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>12</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>13</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>14</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>15</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>16</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

### JavaScript solution with flexbox

Get all `.square`. Loop through them and loop through their children and add a style to each of them.

```
child.setAttribute("style", "width: ...; height: ...")
```

The size is `calc(100% / Math.sqrt(number of square items))`

#### Example

```js
var squares = document.querySelectorAll(".square");

for (var i = 0; i < squares.length; i += 1) {
  for (var j = 0; j < squares[i].children.length; j += 1) {
    var child = squares[i].children[j],
      size = "calc(100% /" + Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(squares[i].children.length)) + ")";
    child.setAttribute("style", "width: " + size + "; height: " + size);
  }
}
```

```css
.square-wrapper {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.square {
  --size: 160px;
}

.square {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-content: start;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
}

.square>div {
  box-shadow: 1px 3px 3px #abc;
  position: relative;
}

.square p {
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div class="square-wrapper">
  <div class="square">
    <div>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>5</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="square-wrapper">
  <div class="square">
    <div>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square-wrapper">
  <div class="square">
    <div>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>8</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>9</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="square-wrapper">
  <div class="square">
    <div>
      <p>1</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>2</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>3</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>4</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>5</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>6</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>7</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>8</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>9</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>10</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>11</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>12</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>13</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>14</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>15</p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>16</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, you have changed the markup a bit which effects the code. I solved this myself with a similar approach you followed. Basically calculating the width of each box by `boxWidth = containerWidth/Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(nodes.length))`. And then applying inline styling to all boxes with width set as `boxWidth`. Of course I had to also use flexbox styling for container box to achieve the desired behaviour: `display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; align-content: flex-start`

Comment: That's right. The reason, why I've changed the markup, was to center the content horizontally and vertically with `<p></p>`. And took different names to make it more clear.